# selector for actionBarItemBackground not working

Tags: android-actionbar

I have to following problem, I want to change the selector from the actionbar item (just the normal actionbar, neither support actionbar nor actionbarsherlock). The backgroud color should be grey instead of default blue if the item icon is pressed. I have searched a lot and know that I need to override the attribute android:actionBarItemBackground in styles, but still my selector doesnt work, the background color is transparent, but the color in on pressed state is not grey, it stays transparent. :/

here is my code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
     <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_bar_item_drawable</item>

</style>
```

and here the drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you supply a selector as a drawable, the first matching item that satisfies all conditions will be displayed.

In your drawable, the transparent color gets chosen every time because it doesn't have any condition such as `state_pressed="true"`.

You should put items with more restricting conditions first and item without any condition as the last one.

Your drawable should instead look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```